# Laravel Select Field: How to get selected the saved value of a Model

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-form

On the Edit view I have a Select field and I want that select field to have the **saved** value for a given Model to be selected.

mediaController.php

```
public function edit($id)
{
    //
     $media = Media::find($id);
     $categories = Category::lists('category', 'id');
     return view('medias.edit-media')->with('media', $media)->with('categories', $categories);
}
```

edit.blade.php

```
   <div class="form-group">
       {!! Form::select('categories', $categories, $media->category ) !!}
   </div>
```

On the index view (i.e the first Media as a Category of Video)

[image]

On the edit view (the first Media doesn't have the Category 'Video' selected)

[image]

even if I change my edit.blade.php to this: ...

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Category of Upload
        <select name="category" id="category" class="form-control input-sm">
            @foreach($categories as $category)
            <option value="{{ $category }}" {{ Input::old($media->category) == $category ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{ $category }}</option>

            @endforeach
           </select>
    </label>

</div>
```

I still have the same result (the right Category is not selected)

Comment: First of all did you getting value of $media->category in edit view template ?

Comment: you are doing it right, just verify that $media->category is not null

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="form-group"><label>Category of Upload <select name="category" id="category" class="form-control input-sm"> @foreach($categories as $category) <option value="{{ $category->id }}" {{ $media->categories == $category->id ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{ $category }}</option>@endforeach </select> </label></div>
```

Comment: this is not what the author wanted to know, he wants to make use of select option of the form facade